# rviz setup error

Tags: rviz

[image: Rosanswers logo]

According   to Tutorial   setup      （Ubuntu10.04   ROS ELECTRIC   version）

first      run   rosdep install rviz       rosmake rviz  rosrun rviz rviz      rviz  not  work  ??

run command output :
rviz revision number 1.6.7
ogre_tools revision number 1.6.3
compiled against OGRE version 1.7.3 (Cthugha)
Loading general config from [/home/robot/.rviz/config]
Loading display config from [/home/robot/.rviz/display_config]
RTT preferred mode is PBbuffer
The program 'rviz' received an X Window System error.
This probably reflects a bug in the program.
The error was 'Baddrawable
(Details: serial 17 error_code 16 request_code 153 minor_code 17)
(Note to programmers: normally, X errors are reported asynchronously;
that is, you will receive the error a while after causing it.
To debug your program, run it with the --sync command line
option to change this behavior. You can then get a meaningful
backtrace from your debugger if you break on the gdk_x_error() function.)

glxinfo gives me this：

robot@robot:~$  glxinfo |grep version
server glx version string: 1.2
client glx version string: 1.4
GLX version: 1.2
OpenGL version string: 2.1 Mesa 7.7.1
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.20

Any ideas what I might be doing wrong? Thanks.( I  can success  rosrun turtlesim turtlesim_node   )

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/189306/rviz--setup--error/) by [Eric.long](https://answers.ros.org/users/19963/eric.long/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2014-08-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Several things:

- You're using very old versions of ROS and Ubuntu. These are not supported any more.
- The old version of rviz that you're using probably doesn't work well without a dedicated graphics card. Do you have an Nvidia graphics card, and have you tried installing the drivers for it?

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-08-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Eric.long](https://answers.ros.org/users/19963/eric.long/) on 2014-08-07**:
do you  know    how   to   update   GLX  version     ？
for  example   ：server glx version string: 1.4
client glx version string: 1.4
GLX version: 1.4

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-08-07**:
Do you have an Nvidia graphics card, and have you tried installing the drivers for it?

**Comment by [Eric.long](https://answers.ros.org/users/19963/eric.long/) on 2014-08-07**:
no,   which you are using    ros and ubuntu verison

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-08-07**:
The old versions of rviz don't work very without a graphics card. I recommend upgrading to one of the newer versions of rviz in ROS Hydro and Ubuntu 12.04, or ROS Indigo and Ubuntu 14.04.

**Comment by [Eric.long](https://answers.ros.org/users/19963/eric.long/) on 2014-08-08**:
thanks  for  your  help        I SELECT   ROS Hydro and Ubuntu 12.04  ,     but   this  version   not   support
pr2   ?

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-08-08**:
You made no mention of PR2 before. The most recent version of ROS with full support for the PR2 was ROS Groovy.